# Angular2 HTTP service for localhost Web API running on different port

Tags: http, angular

I am getting below error when using HTTP service in angular2 with localhost WEB Api. When using URL directly in browser it is working fine and returning JSON result.

**An error occurred Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null**

```
 import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

 @Injectable()
 export class QuizDalService {

 private quizquestionUrl = 'http://localhost:59786/api/AngularQuiz';

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getQuizQuestions(name: string): Promise<mcquestion[]>{
 return this.http.get(this.quizquestionUrl)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then(response => response.json().data as mcquestion[])
                        .catch(this.handleError);
   }
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: How do you call `getQuizQuestions()`?

Comment: Somehow you are nulling your url at somewhere

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak I have logged the URL inside my function it is dispaying correct URL.

Comment: @Dinistro - I am using Service to call this method in my component like -  this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name).then(mcquiz => {this.queslist = mcquiz; });

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and I believe it is because angular 2 when run from the cli runs in a sandbox. It therefore can't see any localhost addresses outside of it. I *think* the solution will be to give my localhost api a url.